# Chartboost moregames page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

How to avoid duplicate games entry in chart boost more games section?

[image]

Here is my code, and added more than one campaign to fill entries….is there any way to restrict duplicate?

```
-(void)initChartboost
{
       Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
    cb.delegate = self;
    //change here
    cb.appId = CHARTBOOST_APPID;
    cb.appSignature = CHARTBOOST_APPSIGNATURE;

    [cb startSession];
    [cb cacheMoreApps];
}

-(void)showMoreGames
{
    if([self connected])
    {
        Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];        
        [cb showMoreApps];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* alert= [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection!" message: @"Checkout your internet connectivity!"
                                                       delegate: NULL cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: NULL] autorelease];

        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a temporary glitch that Chartboost was experiencing a few days ago. It's been resolved, so you don't have to do anything to fix it!

It is fine to add the same campaign in multiple slots on the more apps page, so please feel free to set it up this way for convenience!

Full disclosure: I work for Chartboost.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same campaign in the More Apps page.

Comment: that shows only one game in more list...I wish to have more than one game that is not our own.